# ios development in windows

Tags: macos, mac, development, vmware

I have HP-2000-Notebook Pavilion series with windows on it. More my notebook doesn't support visualization technology.

I want to develop and iOS app in objective c. Is there any alternative that work for me? rather than buying apple notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, apple requires that apps are build in Xcode.

Comment: And what if only want to start now as objective C.

Comment: You can write objective c in any sdk you like, but to publish your apps on an mac or iDevice, the need to be compiled in xCode